# -canOpenURL: failed for URL error for facebook and other social networks

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I have a problem with facebook and vk.com integration. When I'm trying to authorize a user all I get is

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"
```

and

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "vkauthorize://authorize" - error: "(null)"
```

in the console.

I already updated info.plist like that:

```
<dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
        <string>wechat</string>
        <string>line</string>
        <string>instagram</string>
        <string>kakaotalk</string>
        <string>pinterest</string>
        <string>vk</string>
        <string>vkauthorize</string>
    </array>
....
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

but it still don't work on device/simulator. 
What did I miss?

I'm using Facebook SDK 4.6

P.S. tried Facebook SDK 4.7.0

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the source of all the troubles in my case.

There were incredible mistakes in my plist.info.

1. In URL schemes fb app id was like "fb(nnnnnnn)" (the right format is "fbnnnnnnn").
2. in FacebookAppId my app id was like "{nnnnnnn}" (the right format is "nnnnnn").

I don't think these mistakes were made by me, but I can't be sure here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but I had the same error so replacing pod

```
pod 'FacebookCore'

pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

with

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.0'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.0'
```

solved my problem. Might be helpful to someone.

Comment: I am using 'FBSDKLoginKit','~>5.0'     but still getting same error